# How to save modified mask value into azure SQL database with original value but not an mask value?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, data-masking

I implemented the dynamic data masking concept in my current project using this below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dynamic-data-masking-get-started

I added the mask for SSN field then after that I am able to see only masked data of SSN filed like XXXX-XX-0001. But whenever I was modified SSN filed (XXXX-XX-0002) and save into azure SQL database there masked data will be saved not an original SSN value.

How can I save the updated mask value into Azure SQL database with original value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dynamic-data-masking-get-started) states about DDM:

> Dynamic data masking helps prevent unauthorized access to sensitive data by enabling customers to designate how much of the sensitive data to reveal with minimal impact on the application layer. It’s a policy-based security feature that **hides the sensitive data in the result set of a query** over designated database fields, while the data in the database is not changed.

**Dynamic data masking policy**

> **SQL users excluded from masking** - A set of SQL users or AAD identities that will get unmasked data in the SQL query results. Note that **users with administrator privileges will always be excluded from masking**, and will see the original data without any mask.

And the purpose of dynamic data masking is to limit exposure of sensitive data, preventing users who should not have access to the data from viewing it.

According to your description, I assumed that your SQL user has **write permissions** but without **UNMASK** privileges. At this point, when you update SSN field into Azure SQL database, then your SSN field would contain statically masked data.

For granting Permissions to View Unmasked Data, you could grant the **UNMASK** permission to your SQL user as follows:

```html
GRANT UNMASK TO TestUser;  
EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestUser';  
SELECT * FROM Membership;  
REVERT;   

-- Removing the UNMASK permission  
REVOKE UNMASK TO TestUser;
```

Or you could log into Azure Portal, type the SQL users or AAD identities that should be excluded from masking as follows:

[image]

In summary, since you are using DDM to hide the sensitive data in the result of a query, you'd better do not grant the user with **write permissions** (db_datawriter db role). You could follow the "Best Practices and Common Use Cases" section from this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt130841.aspx). Also, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4213/configure-and-customize-sql-azure-dynamic-data-masking/) about configure and Customize SQL Azure Dynamic Data Masking.